# Images being cut off HTML

Tags: html, css

I am designing a HTML site for a friend of mine.

example.thoseitguys.co.za/template/expectations.html

That page for some reason is cutting my image on the right side.

Is there some CSS i have missed that is limiting the size of the image or the width of the page?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: We do not leave this site and go somewhere else to figure out what you're asking or look at your code. Please spend some time reading [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: please show some code.....

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Put it in a div and make the width 100% like this:

```
﻿﻿<div>
    <img src="style/images/test.png" alt="" style="width: 100%">
</div>
```

Comment: Answering questions based on code or HTML that is not here in the question itself is inappropriate. If the poster uses this code to fix the problem at their site, then this question has zero future value here and should be deleted. Answering it removes any incentive for the poster to edit to provide the information here. If the relevant code is not here, in the question itself, then that code does not exist and you can't use it to provide an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Add a class to your image. Something like:

`<img class="howWeDoIt" src="style/images/test.png" alt="" >`

On your CSS do:

`howWeDoIt {
    width: 100%;
}`

Comment: Answering questions based on code or HTML that is not here in the question itself is inappropriate. If the poster uses this code to fix the problem at their site, then this question has zero future value here and should be deleted. Answering it removes any incentive for the poster to edit to provide the information here. If the relevant code is not here, in the question itself, then that code does not exist and you can't use it to provide an answer.

Comment: I agree 100%. Tnx

Answer (score -1):

If you want it to scale perfectly to what is visible on your screen, you should do something similar to what is shown below. I have used this method for my Garry's Mod server loading screen. It scales to your screen size. You can view that loading image that scales automatically here: http://nubsite.gaming.bz/images/loadingscreen.php

Now to the code you will need to scale to screen size:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .bg {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: -5000;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <img src="[YOUR IMAGE URL HERE]" class="bg">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```